# how to convert a sql query into linq to entity query?

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

```
  select sr.Name as Sale_Rep,ag.Name as Agent ,
         sum(tr.Amount) Debit_tran 
  from DebtorTransactions as tr 
       join Warranty as wr on tr.ProductID=wr.Id 
       join Agents as ag on ag.pkfAgentID=wr.fldAgentID 
       join SalesReps as sr on wr.fldSrId =sr.pkfSrID 
  where tr.Product=0  
  group by ag.Name, sr.Name
```

i want to convert this query into Linq to Entity but can't ... can some convert this query into Linq to entity for me plz

This is what I've tried:

```
var abc= from tr in db.DebtorTransactions 
         from wr in db.Warranties 
         from sr in db.SalesReps 
         from ag in db.Agents 
         where tr.ProductID==wr.Id 
            && ag.pkfAgentID==wr.fldAgentID 
            && wr.fldSrId ==sr.pkfSrID 
            && tr.Product==0 
         select new { ag.Name, sr.Name, tr.Amount };
```

But i don't get any output

Comment: var abc= from tr in db.DebtorTransactions
                         from wr in db.Warranties
                         from sr in db.SalesReps
                         from ag in db.Agents
                         where tr.ProductID==wr.Id &&
                         ag.pkfAgentID==wr.fldAgentID &&
                         wr.fldSrId ==sr.pkfSrID &&
                         tr.Product==0
                         select new
                         {
                             ag.Name,
                             sr.Name,
                             tr.Amount
                         };

Comment: i have tried this ...but i don't get any output...plz help me

Answer (score 1):

To match your SQL query you'll need to group by the same columns:

```
from tr in db.DebtorTransactions 
join wr in db.Warranties on tr.ProductID equals wr.Id
join ag in db.Agents on wr.fldAgentID equals ag.pkfAgentID
join sr in db.SalesReps on wr.fldSrId equals sr.pkfSrID 
group tr 
    by new { Sale_Rep = sr.Name, Agent = ag.Name }
    into transactions
select new {
    transactions.Key.Sale_Rep,
    transactions.Key.Agent,
    Debit_tran = transactions.Sum(tr => tr.Amount)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc = from tr in db.DebtorTransactions 
          join wr in db.Warranties tr.ProductID equals wr.Id
          join sr in db.SalesReps wr.fldSrId equals sr.pkfSrID 
          join ag in db.Agents wr.fldAgentID equals ag.pkfAgentID
          where tr.Product==0 
          select new { ag.Name, sr.Name, tr.Amount };
```